# Scala - ReadLines with linenumber awareness

Tags: scala, file-io

I am trying to read from a (\n separated) file in Scala. I would like to treat the last and second to last line of the file differently from the others. how do I achieve this? As far as I know, `LineNumberedReader` which is a `BufferedReader` can get the current line number but is not aware of the total number of lines(to process the last line differently). Desired:

```
var aLine = lineNumberedReader.readLine
while (aLine != null) {
   val currentLineNum: Int = lineNumberedReader.getLineNumber
   if (currentLineNum == total_line_count - 1) {
       do_this // To know if its the last line/ second to last, I need the total_line_count available in hand. which I (maybe incorrectly?) believe needs a file iteration by itself
   } else {
       do_that
   }
   aLine = lineNumberedReader.readLine
}
```

Same issues exist with Scala `io.Source`. it requires a minimum of two file iterations. Any ideas/APIs using which this can be achieved using a single iteration?

**EDIT**: Extending the question to include case for second-to-last line

Comment: Finding the (end - n) line is a different question.  It can't be done without knowing where the end is ahead of time, which requires a complete traversal.

Comment: @jwvh it doesn't require a complete traversal, just looking n lines ahead ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
val lines = Source
  .fromFile("filename")
  .getLines
lines.foreach { line => 
   if (lines.hasNext) doThis(line) else doThat(line)
}
```

For one before last it gets a bit more involved:

```
val it = Source.fromFile("filename").getLines.sliding(2)
it.foreach { 
 case x :: _ if it.hasNext => doCommon(x) 
 case x :: y :: _ => doBeforeLast(x); doLast(y)
}
```

Or in general for N-before-last (before you edit your question again :D):

```
val it = Source.fromFile("filename").getLines.sliding(n+1)
it.foreach {
  case x :: _ if it.hasNext => doCommon(x)
  case tail => doNBeforeLast(tail)
}
```

Comment: This actually does solve a part of my problem, which is to process the last line differently. I also have a use case for processing the last but one line differently. I meant to ask that as well but my scattered mind did not construct a clear question.  Any ideas on how to extend the solution. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Added a snippet for looking for the one-before-last line

Comment: Thank you. I learnt quite a lot from your answer, I appreciate it!